# HERE Maps: Realtime coverage for public transit API

Tags: rest, maps, here-api, here-maps-rest

Does anyone manage to get real time information from the [HERE Maps Public Transit API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html)?

Inputting coordinates for Central Station (Sydney, Australia) to Circular Quay Station using simple routing like so:

```
https://transit.ls.hereapi.com/v3/route.json?dep=-33.883271,151.207000&arr=-33.861508%2C151.210564&time=2019-12-31T22:30:00&routing=sr&apiKey=<apiKey>
```

which is [covered](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/coverage-information.html) under real time returns:

```
{
    "Res": {
        "serviceUrl": "https://transit.ls.hereapi.com/transit/v3/route.json",
        "Message": {
            "code": "GW0001",
            "level": "E",
            "subcode": "NO_COV",
            "text": "Out of coverage"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the real time transit route there is a parameter called

> **routingMode = realtime**

see the below request (Removed routing from your request: not a valid parameter)

```
https://transit.ls.hereapi.com/v3/route.json?dep=-33.883271,151.207000&arr=-33.861508%2C151.210564&time=2020-01-02T16:32:00&apiKey=your_apiKey&routingMode=realtime
```

For detail documentation please visit [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/resource-routing.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer! Just one more question - is it possible to view how late/early say a bus or a train is from the API? For example, would it be possible to calculate that some train is 5 minutes late.

Comment: early/later journey was there which is now deprecated so now either you can choose routingMode as schedule (default) which returns the time table data based route and another one is realtime.https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/resource-earlier-later-routing.html